# Different outputs from &pointer and pointer (C++)

Tags: c++, pointers

I was tinkering about with pointers and noticed something that I don't quite understand... 
When I check for the value of a pointer, the address changes slightly wether I use &pointer or only the pointer to return..

Here's an example.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    int i = 40;
    int *pi = &i;

    std::cout<< *pi << "   " << &pi << "  " << pi << std:: endl;
}
```

I got this in return..

```
40   010FFB38  010FFB50
```

First one is *p, second &p and third just p

This is likely is simple answer but I can't find it anywhere so what does it mean? What is the difference between &p and simply p?

Comment: The same as for an int or a double or anything else.

Comment: what do you mean? @juanchopanza

Comment: Well, what does `&` do when applied to a thing?

Comment: An `int` holds an integer. A pointer holds an address. The address of the pointer is orthogonal to the value it holds.

Comment: `pi` is a pointer to i (the memory address of i). So `pi` like `i` is a variable, which is stored somewhere in the memory. &pi, is the address of the variable pi: this is the memory location where you have stored the memory location of i...

Comment: yeah just noticed this is a duplicate.. sorry.. @v1bri

Comment: If they were the same then there wouldn't be any point to the `&` operator existing ...

Answer (score 1):

`p` is a pointer, pointing to memory location holding variable `i`.

`&p` on the other hand returns a pointer to where variable `p` is stored, which is a different location than the one that holds `i`.

Comment: so pointer p's location is in &p and i's location is in p

Comment: @iMarioOfficial sort of yes, `&p` is a [reference operator](https://www.codingunit.com/cplusplus-tutorial-pointers-reference-and-dereference-operators) applied to variable `p`.

Answer (score 1):

`&p` prints the address in main memory where the pointer is stored, compared to `p` which prints the contents stored in that memory address, which in your case is the address of the variable `i`.

Answer (score 1):

*pi : Dereference the pointer pi and get to the memory location that it points to.

---

&pi : 'Address of pi' , so this refers to the address at which the pointer pi is stored.

---

pi : This is pi itself, this stores the address at which the value 40 is stored.